# Windows Server 64 bit on a 32 bit Machine

Tags: windows

I have Windows Server and by the looks of the install disk it seems to be a 64 bit version.  Can this be installed and run successfully on 32 bit hardware?

It's Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: how do you have a 32-bit machine in today's world?

Comment: @warren I am pushing this out to a desktop pc that is 32the bit. Just for learning/development and I wanted Windows Server to be the OS.

Comment: Are you sure it's really 32-bit? What CPU does it have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows Server 2008 R2 is ONLY 64 bit.  There is no 32 bit version.  It will not be able to be run successfully on 32 bit hardware, unfortunately.

Comment: I am getting this through dreamspark and the minimum system requirements have specs for 32 bit systems as well. Why would that be??

Comment: The Windows 7 Client can be 32-bit or if you had access to Windows Server 2008 (not R2) you can get the 32-bit install. I believe you can use Oracle VirtualBox to run a 64-bit VM on 32-bit hardware, but you would still need an OS on the machine first.

Comment: @Top__Hat I can get Windows Server 2008. So you're saying I can run that on 32the bit machine then??

Comment: @Shark - there *is* a 32-bit version of Server 2008, so if you installed that, it would work

Comment: @Shark - What Mark said is exactly right. Windows Server 2008 comes in 32-bit and 64-bit flavors. If there isn't something specific to the R2 release you want/need to test just use the 32-bit Windows Server 2008 install.